# What OS distribution inside poky?

Tags: yocto

When we follow the steps

https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/3.0.2/brief-yoctoprojectqs/brief-yoctoprojectqs.html

to build a yocto image.

What is the OS inside this image? Ubuntu? CentOS? or nothing else?

Which installation method I can use in yocto? yum or apt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reference distribution in Yocto is called Poky. So it's not Ubuntu, CentOS or something like that. It's Poky. And if you customize it, you'll have your very own distribution.

See https://www.yoctoproject.org/software-overview/reference-distribution/.

Answer (score 0):

It's a Yocto custom embedded Linux.

You have to state every tool you would want the image to have. For example, if you want apt-get, you will need to update local.conf with:

```
EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES += " package-management "
```

Comment: I added this line in local.conf, rebuild the image, however, I still can't use yum, only rpm command is valid.

Comment: If I need to use dnf, how to add a valid repo?

Comment: You can search OE layer index for all available recipes/layers https://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/branch/master/recipes/